# Compiler adds padding to already aligned union bit field member

Tags: c, padding, unions, bit-fields

I am trying to build my own library for converting between integers of different endianness' and signed representations.  Part of this involves directly accessing a char buffers as integers of the same size (mainly for fast comparisons).  I am deeply concerned about portability with this project.&nbsp I want this library to be usable on all machines and c compilers old and new, not just gcc or clang on linux.

Originally I used the c99 fixed width integer types for the integer members.&nbsp This worked fine.&nbsp The problems started when I switched from fixed width integers to bit fields of the same size.  I did this to improve portability by not depending on c99 features.&nbsp

The problem is that when I use a bit field, gcc complains that padding has been inserted (-Werror and -Wpadded were passed to gcc):
**error: padding struct size to alignment boundary**

Here is an example of one of the unions:

Old version, worked fine:

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    uint32_t uvalue;
} upicl_uint32_be;
```

New version, adds unwanted padding:

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    unsigned long uvalue : 32;
} upicl_uint32_be;
```

I have no idea why padding is added to my unions when a 32-bit bit field is already aligned.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The better way, in this case, would be `memcpy`. Honestly if portability to anything with a C compiler is a concern then if fear you'll have to give up bitfields as a lost cause. If you're unlucky your compiler might not support long bitfields. If you're _really_ unlucky it might not even have 8-bit characters. Oh, and are you sure that your C compiler doesn't have >32-bit longs?

Comment: My code checks to make sure CHAR_BIT == 8 and doesn't compile unless this is true.

Comment: So you've given up supporting on all compilers already then? ;)

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding.  I meant the vast majority of compilers (on normal systems with 8 bit characters).

Comment: Zeb Thompson: Sorry, I didn't mean to make light of your efforts at insuring portability. I just meant that doing any real work in fully standard-compliant C is essentially a pointless waste of time (think 6 significant characters in external identifiers in C89). The trick, as you seem to be doing, is to pick a reasonable sub-set suitable for your application and hope you've made an informed choice.

Comment: If you want to write anything portable, you just can't use bitfields.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `long` is 8 bytes long, so the bitfield will occupy 8 bytes, since it is not the same size as `uint32_t`.

The name of the union type suggests that you intended the bitfield to be based on `uint32_t` rather than `unsigned long` (or that you assume the two are the same, which is evidently incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be compiling your code on a 64-bit system, as otherwise `unsigned long` would be the same as `uint32_t`. You can test that the following:

```
typedef union {
   uint32_t uvalue : 1;
} upicl_uint32_be;
```

...also gives the warning. The problem is that you have only 1 bit of data, yet the `uint32_t` forces it to occupy 32 bits.

If you don't want to have the warning, use the type `unsigned int`. On practically all systems except some microcontrollers `unsigned int` is guaranteed to be 32 bits. But in my opinion the use of `uint32_t` is the best choice as it's always guaranteed to be 32 bits.

You could write some `#define` hacks to see which basic type is 32 bits but I wouldn't recommend such hacks. Consider that C99 is over 15 years old, so practically all compilers support it.

Comment: Sadly while `<stdint.h>` is fairly common in general full C99 support is more the exception than the rule. MSVC famously still doesn't bother and in the embedded world where I spend my days it's pretty much a write-off unless the compiler is GCC-based. Maybe one day I'll be able to start taking advantage of all those nifty new features..

Comment: I guess this means I should stick with with c99 fixed width integer types.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think most compilers that don't implement C99 still have `<stdint.h>` so you should be safe in using it. If you ever run into a compiler that doesn't have `<stdint.h>` you can emulate it with `#define` hacks. I'm not suggesting to use these `#define` hacks if you already have support for `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a 4 byte unsigned long native you can use the alignment syntax to set it.

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned long unused : 0;
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    unsigned long uvalue : 32;

} upicl_uint32_be;
```

might do the trick.

Another possibility is just reverse the order so the compiler sees the unsigned long first.

```
typedef union
{
    unsigned long uvalue : 32;
    unsigned char bytes[4];

} upicl_uint32_be;
```

one last thing to try doubles are typically 8 bytes

```
typedef union
{
    double unused;
    unsigned char bytes[4];
    unsigned long uvalue : 32;

} upicl_uint32_be;
```